# Reference an object from a column in another table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hbm

I have the following object model:

```
class ObjectA{
    public string Description {get;set;}
}

class ObjectB{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public ObjectA A {get;set;}
}

class ObjectC{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public ObjectB B {get;set;}
}

class ObjectD{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public ObjectC C {get;set;}
    public ObjectA A {get;set;}
}
```

My tables are as follows:

A: ID(int), DESCRIPTION(string)

B: ID(int), DESCRIPTION(string), A_ID(int)

C: ID(int), DESCRIPTION(string), B_ID(int)

D: ID(int), DESCRIPTION(string), C_ID(int), A_ID(int)

In table D A_ID is a foreign key to the primary key of table A.  This was originally done so that you could easily access `ObjectA` from `ObjectD`: `ObjectD.A`.  This is causing the ID from table A to have to be added to every table that wants to access `ObjectA` in this manner de-normalizing the database (imagine having `ObjectE`, and `ObjectF` that all want to easily access `ObjectA`).  In this case `ObjectB` will always have a reference to `ObjectA`.

I'd like to get rid of the reference to A_ID in all of my tables but I want to be able to easily access `ObjectA` from my classes.  I know I could do `ObjectD.ObjectC.ObjectB.ObjectA` to get `ObjectA` when needed but that seems to defeat the purpose of lazy loading my objects.

How can I map my `ObjectD` so that I can have direct access to `ObjectA` without having `ObjectA`'s ID in `ObjectD`'s table?

**Note:** I'm using hbm/xml files to map my classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you either live with the redundant data for performance reasons or you don't. I can't conceive of a third option. (But there are better NHibernate minds out there that may correct this view).

If the reads of these objects are much higher than the writes and the use cases require access to ObjectA most of the time you're working with an ObjectD then the redundancy is fine. Otherwise the ObjectD.C.B.A approach you refer starts to become more attractive.